# All of my Google Chrome extensions have stopped working on Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: google-chrome

I have noticed that my Google Chrome extensions are no longer working on Ubuntu or Windows, and the context menu of each extension is no longer showing up. I have noticed that this problem seems to occur on both Linux and Windows in Google Chrome, so it is most likely not platform-specific. EDIT: The problem has been resolved in Windows after disabling all extensions.

Comment: I don't see how this could be related. Yet you should remove the extensions and then the extensions' directory manually (that should be rm -rf ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions) and reinstall them through the Chrome Webstore. I experienced something similar some time ago and only got rid of the not working extensions by manually deleting their directory. You'll lose the extensions' settings though, I guess.

Comment: As suggested, it's most likely unrelated to the kernel update. It's probable that something in your profile is corrupted. My suggestion is even more drastic than the one above. Back up your bookmarks and note your passwords; then turn off Chrome completely, including Background Apps, and then rename `~/.config/google-chrome` to something else and restart Chrome.

Comment: Google Chrome is working properly again for no apparent reason. I hope it stays this way!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem seems to be back now, and it affects my Chrome installation on Windows as well as Ubuntu. I tried disabling all extensions, and everything seems to be working again, at least for now.

Comment: If it's Windows-related(or occurring on both OS's), it *cannot* be fixed here.

Comment: In that case, I think this question should be moved to Superuser and the title should be renamed.

Comment: Just create a new question, and out of curiosity, can I have a link to the new question?
=

Comment: Here's the new question: http://superuser.com/questions/450731/all-of-my-google-chrome-extensions-have-stopped-working